# SWAPI Async-Await - ¿Por que un Array que contiene objetos aparece como vacío (Array(0))?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, promesas, async-await

Estoy tratando de imprimir el nombre de los personajes de Star Wars y en que peliculas han aparecido dentro de la saga, obteniendo los datos con SWAPI y utilizando jQuery para las peticiones.
Ya tengo los nombres de los personajes en un Array, y también un Array con sus respectivas películas (solo las URL),

[image: URLs de películas]

pero cuando intento obtener los nombres de esas películas usando `Promise` y `push()`, obtengo un Array de Arrays que parecen vacíos pero no lo están.

[image: Arrays vacíos]

Como parecen vacíos no puedo acceder a la información que contienen con `[index][index]`, ya que obtengo un `undefined`

Este el código en JS:

```js
const API_URL = "https://swapi.dev/api/";
const PEOPLE_URL = "people/:id/";
const FILMS_URL = "films/:id/";
const OPTIONS = { crossDomain: true };

getCharacters(4); //Obtiene los datos de n personajes

function getCharacter (idCharacter) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        const CHARACTER_URL = `${API_URL}${PEOPLE_URL.replace(':id', idCharacter)}`; //URL del personaje
    $
        .get(CHARACTER_URL, OPTIONS, character => resolve(character)) //Obtiene el objeto de un personaje
        .fail(errIdCharacter => reject(errIdCharacter));
    });
}

function getFilms(urlsFilms){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let filmsNames = [] // Array de los títulos de las películas
        urlsFilms.forEach(films => { //Recorre todo el Array y obtiene cada URl de cada pelicula
            $
                .get(films, OPTIONS, film => filmsNames.push(film.title)) //Agrega el título de la película al Array de títulos
                .fail(errFilms => reject(errFilms));
        })
        resolve(filmsNames)
    })
}

async function getCharacters(counter){ //Obtiene los objetos de los personajes
    let ids = []; //Array para contar y ordenar a los personajes
    for(let i = 1; i <= counter; i++){
        ids.push(i);
    }

    let characterPromises = ids.map(idCharacter => getCharacter(idCharacter));
    let characters = await Promise.all(characterPromises);
    let charactersNames = characters.map(character => character.name);
    let charactersFilms = characters.map(character => character.films);
    let filmsPromises = charactersFilms.map(films => getFilms(films));
    let filmsNames = await Promise.all(filmsPromises);

    console.log(charactersFilms); //Imprime un Array de Arrays con las URL de la películas
    console.log(charactersFilms[0][0]); //Imprime la URL de la primer pelicula del primer personaje
    console.log(filmsPromises); //Imprime las promesas para obtener los objetos de las películas
    console.log(filmsNames); //Imprime el Array de Arrays que parecen vacios
    console.log(filmsNames[0][0]); //imprime un undefined

    /* for(let i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        console.log(`Hola, soy ${charactersNames[i]} y quizas que conozcas por aparecer en películas como:`);
        charactersFilms[i].forEach(film => console.log(film))
    } */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="CharactersFilms.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en el `getFilms`, en el bucle que haces de urlFilms no se esta esperando a que se completen los gets, para hacer el `resolve(filmsNames)`, es decir creo que esta haciendo el resolve sin esperarse a hacer las llamadas de dentro del bucle que son las que rellenan el array.

Creo que habría que hacer otro Promise.all de ese bucle interno para que cuando llegue al `resolve(filmsNames)` ya haya acabado todas las llamadas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si era eso. Lo corregí agregando las promesas de los títulos a un Array y después haciendo un Array con esos Arrays. Y para obtener el Array de los nombres hice  un `Promise.all()` a cada Array de promesas.